# Paypal PaymentDetails API error 540031

Tags: android, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to integrate Paypal adaptive chained payment. I'm totally new at this so please bear with me. I'm getting the paykey. But when I try to get transaction id from PaymentDetails API, I'm getting this error code with message `You+do+not+have+permission+to+get+these+payment+details`. Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error? The same credentials are being used in iOS and its working.

```css
Envelope.timestamp=2017-04-18T01%3A50%3A24.907-07%3A00&responseEnvelope.ack=Failure&responseEnvelope.correlationId=adc36cc2d80b5&responseEnvelope.build=32250686&error(0).errorId=540031&error(0).domain=PLATFORM&error(0).subdomain=Application&error(0).severity=Error&error(0).category=Application&error(0).message=You+do+not+have+permission+to+get+these+payment+details
```

```html
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        StringBuffer buffer;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = null;
                httppost = new HttpPost("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/PaymentDetails");

                httppost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID","ashishapp.gmail.com");
                httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD","P9AGL37BV9TLZ9RD");
                httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE","AyW8vijLhnQYFtANgDxD3mbhZZi8PawPbRFvGFb3sy2TNzaMZcVtvzEZ");
                httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID","APP-80W284485P519543T");
                httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");
                httppost.setHeader("X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "NV");

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("payKey", "AP-8PA68871T0961962Y"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("requestEnvelope.errorLanguage", "en_US"));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                byte[] data1;
                data1 = new byte[256];
                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int len = 0;
                while (-1 != (len = is.read(data1))) {
                    buffer.append(new String(data1, 0, len));
                }
                System.out.println("sammy--------->" + buffer.toString());
                is.close();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            System.out.println("sammy_onPost "+result);
        }



    }
```

Comment: can you file a ticket to MTS? This error is very subtle and not specific. MTS could help on this.File it here https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Answer (score 0):

The error code 540031 means that "You do not have permission to get these payment options". You may refer to the link below.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/GetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why in Android I'm having this error when iOS does not?